# how to order a mysql varchar field with assumed col values?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How to order a varchar field with assumed date values:
eg: .

```
February 2014, April 2014, Q1 2014, Q2 2014
```

I need to order the field date wise ascending(or descending) with assuming Q1=March, Q2=October,

so it should order like:

```
February 2014, Q1 2014, April 2014,  Q2 2014
```

Comment: Is all that data stored in a single row/column?  Or is that multiple rows? It's not exactly clear from your question.

Comment: no one value in a row/column, eg: 'February 2014'

Comment: February 2014, April 2014, Q1 2014, Q2 2014 are  4 different values of a varchar column field

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem? Or did you figure it out? Even if you figured it out for yourself it is nice to post the answer for others who are having similar problems or credit the person that helped you arrive at the solution.

Answer (score 0):

CAST you VARCHAR values to DATETIME values then the bulit in mysql ORDER BY asc/desc will work properly.  If you don't have a day just set all the days to the 1st of the month.  I have no idea what those Q values are but that is no date format that I have seen and I am pretty sure mysql won't konw what to do with it either.

Comment: order Q1 2014 with assuming it as March 2014 is the real issue.

Comment: So I am assuming you have preset values for these Q values, so you can set up a select case or if statement where if values contains Q1 then tempdate='March' Are you sure Q2 is October and not Q3?  I am assuming Q is for quarter and a quarter can't be 6 months long.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont appear to have other alternatives identifying a standard sequencing, you might be able to get what you want with a structured order by case/when construct such as...  Your quarters don't make sense as March to October is more than 3 months apart...  But lets assume you Financial calendar starts in Jan, so March is the last month of first quarter...

```
order by
   case when YourField like 'Jan%' then '01'
   when YourField like 'Feb%' then '02'
   when YourField like 'Mar%' then '03a'
   when YourField like 'Q1%'  then '03b'
   when YourField like 'Apr%' then '04'
   when YourField like 'May%' then '05'
   when YourField like 'Jun%' then '06a'
   when YourField like 'Q2%'  then '06b'
   when YourField like 'Jul%' then '07'
   when YourField like 'Aug%' then '08'
   when YourField like 'Sep%' then '09a'
   when YourField like 'Q3%'  then '09b'
   when YourField like 'Oct%' then '10'
   when YourField like 'Nov%' then '11'
   when YourField like 'Dec%' then '12a'
   when YourField like 'Q4%' then '12b' end
```

But a more efficient way might be to have a lookup table of what months / quarters represent the order you want... Then join to that.  I have the "a" and "b" versions so if your data DID have both a March and Q1 entry, the March would be listed first, then Q1.  You can't use just a month numeric of the literal as Q would always sort at the end and not give you what you need.

Also, if your Financial calendar does not start on Jan 1, then your first quarter might start such as Mar, Apr, May for Q1, Jun, Jul, Aug for Q2, etc..

Also, I have the case/when values sorted as '01', '02', etc so as they will always be before '10', '11' and '12' entries.

Answer (score 0):

I have no DB where I could test this, nor do I have mysql installed so take this as more of pseudo code than an exactly syntactically correct solution but you may want to try something like this...

```
SELECT *, CAST((CASE
    WHEN CONTAINS(dateField, 'Q1') THEN 'March' + SUBSTRING(dateField) 
    WHEN CONTAINS(dateField, 'Q2') THEN 'October' + SUBSTRING(dateField)
    ETC... 
    ELSE datefield) AS DATETIME) as Date1  
FROM mytable
ORDER BY Date1
```